# Why are the radio emissions from a vga cable polarized

Tags: rf, noise, emissions

So im doing this college project for my CS degree, and we're starting to notice that more and more the project falls short on what we've learned, either way i would like to put a complete answer without having a lot of gaps on my essay.

The project is related to TempestSDR, to cut it short, its a program designed to eavesdrop the data sent from a graphics card or chip to a monitor or any device in general that uses a raster scan based system. Although we've been able to get some good images with HDMI i was suprised to know that VGA proves itself to be a lot more difficult to setup in order to have a good image. I've tried using cables that dont have those ferrite shields in order to hopefully have as much emission from the cable it self, but strangely it appears that the VGA cable emissions are polarized, meaning that i can only get a good detailed image by rotating the antenna a certain way.

So the question is: is there any difference in the polarization of emissions between HDMI and VGA if there is why is that the case? we've tried with a lot of different cables and although we gotten some better results unlike HDMI, VGA seems to always have some sort of polarization effect

Also to add we're using a standard monopole antenna that came with the RTL SDR dongle, its very similar to those retractable ones used in old radios and cars

Comment: Polarization is determined by antenna shape. And both your cables are...cables.

Comment: The physics group is more likely to have some useful thoughts. But I'd probably start with a google search; something like, "scattering, radiation, and polarization properties of leaky cables" or some such. Then follow up with what you find.

Comment: The main differene that I am aware of is that VGA is unbalanced while HDMI is balanced

Comment: @Jasen that shouldn't make a difference here

Comment: VGA is also lower frequency.

Comment: @DKNguyen yes you are right and thats precisely why i am perplexed, despite we streching the cables or laying them in a similar way, while the hdmi is a brease to pick up on its signal, the vga seems to only work if we the antenna is at a very odd angle or if we coil the cable around the antenna